# updating ruby-saml causes an error in Onelogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml

I'm writing a custom onmiauth strategy for a provider calld Islykill but after I update ruby-saml from 0.7.3 to 1.0 I'm getting an error when constructing a new Authrequest

You can see my strategy here:
https://github.com/Algrim/omniauth-islykill/tree/update-ruby-saml

The problem happens in [islykill.rb](https://github.com/Algrim/omniauth-islykill/blob/update-ruby-saml/lib/omniauth/strategies/islykill.rb) line:23

I cant figure out what the problem is; can you help me?

Sorry about this ... forgot to provide the stacktrace; here it is:

> NameError (uninitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Islykill::Onelogin):
>    /home/osboxes/development/omniauth-islykill/lib/omniauth/strategies/islykill.rb:26:in `request_phase'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:215:in`request_call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:183:in `call!'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in`call'
>    omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>    activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>    activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
>    activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in`call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>    activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in`run_callbacks'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>    web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>    railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
>    railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
>    activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>    activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
>    activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
>    railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
>    activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>    actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
>    railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
>    railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
>    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
>    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
>
> Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.9ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.9ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (18.0ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (25.2ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
>    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kladdi/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (40.5ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0.7.3 version is a quite old ruby-saml version (21 Feb 2014).

If you check the release [0.8.1](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/releases/tag/0.8.1) you will be able to read:

> Changed namespace of the gem from OneLogin::Saml to
> OneLogin::RubySaml.

So instead of

> authn_request = Onelogin::Saml::Authrequest.new
>
> settings = Onelogin::Saml::Settings.new(options)

you may use:

> authn_request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
>
> settings = OneLogin::RubySaml::Settings.new(options)

Review the documentation and the changelog in order to find more changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; like I said in the question the error occurs when doing:

        authn_request = Onelogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
        settings = Onelogin::RubySaml::Settings.new(options)

So, I am using the correct namespace but still get the error .(

Comment: Review this ruby-saml-example that contains a demo of the use of ruby-saml:  https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

ok, way is the error

> NameError (uninitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Islykill::Onelogin)

Well that is because in my [islykill.rb](https://github.com/Algrim/omniauth-islykill/blob/update-ruby-saml/lib/omniauth/strategies/islykill.rb) I got

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Islykill
    # some code
    request = Onelogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
    # rest of code
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when ruby is unable to find *Onelogin* it starts looking for a class definition within the *class* **Islykill** and that is way it says it can not find **OmniAuth::Strategies::Islykill::Onelogin**

Now I start thinkin why doesn't it find **Onelogin::RubySaml::Authrequest** in the **ruby-saml** gem which is required in the top of the [islykill.rb](https://github.com/Algrim/omniauth-islykill/blob/update-ruby-saml/lib/omniauth/strategies/islykill.rb). There is no error that it can't find the required **ruby-saml**

I just have to find out why I'm not getting a

> `require': cannot load such file -- ruby-saml (LoadError)

but that was not the question.. so, thank you @smartin for your help.

edit:

Well, I figured it out; It could not have been more obvious. There is typo in One**l**ogin ... it is, of course, One**L**ogin

Thank you all and I hope you will not hold this against me next time :)

Comment: Nice to see you solve the issue, sorry but I had no much time to debug your error :(